# How to make a loop of scanf until the user press enter (using only <stdio.h>)

Tags: c, loops, char, scanf

I want to have a loop of scanf that repeats until the user presses enter.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  char num[127];
  int i=-1;
  do
  {
    i++;
    scanf("%c ", &num[i]);
  }while ((num[i]!='\n') && i<=127);

  printf("%c", num[3]);
  return 0;
}
```

With this code, when I input > 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 , the output num[3] is nothing. How can I fix this? I already tried using while and for, but i get the same problem.

Comment: don't use `scanf()` for this. Use `fgets()` to read lines, and parse the line with `sscanf()`.

Comment: Did you try to print `num[0]` or `num[2]` ...?

Comment: Your attempt to avoid overflowing the buffer is flawed.  When `i==127`, the loop continues and attempts to write to `num[128]`.  The maximum valid index is 126.

Comment: Trying to use `scanf` for this is like trying to learn to play a piano sonata while surrounded by five unaccomplished punk rock musicians playing bad guitar riffs through overloaded  amps and screaming incomprehensible lyrics in your face.  Do yourself a big, giant favor and just call `getchar` instead.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is something like the following

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 127 };
    
    char num[N];
    size_t len = 0;
    
    char c;
    
    while ( len < N && scanf( "%c", &c ) == 1 && c != '\n' )
    {
        if ( !isblank( ( unsigned char )c ) ) num[len++] = c;       
    }
    
    if ( 3 < len ) printf( "%c\n", num[3] );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The if statement

```
if ( !isblank( ( unsigned char )c ) ) num[len++] = c;
```

may be substituted for this one if you are going to enter only digits

```
if ( isdigit( ( unsigned char )c ) ) num[len++] = c;
```

If to use `getchar` then the program will look like

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 127 };
    
    char num[N];
    size_t len = 0;
    
    int c;
    
    while ( len < N && ( c = getchar() ) != EOF && c != '\n' )
    {
        if ( isdigit( c ) ) num[len++] = c;     
    }
    
    if ( 3 < len ) printf( "%c\n", num[3] );
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Using the format specifier `"%c "`, `scanf` will never write `\n` into `buf[i]` except for `i == 0`.  (If the first character of input is a newline, it will be written to `buf[0]`.  Otherwise, all newlines will be discarded because of the whitespace in the conversion specifier.)  If you are entering data interactively, the program will not terminate correctly, since eventually the `scanf` will invoke undefined behavior when it tries to write to `buf[127]`

Also, you're not checking the value returned by scanf.  It's not clear to me what you want to do with whitespace, but perhaps you want something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int
main(void)
{
        char num[127];
        int i=-1;
        while( i < 125 && scanf("%c", &num[++i]) == 1 && num[i] != '\n' ){
                ; /* scanf is the wrong tool for this!! */
        }
        printf("%c", num[3]);
        return 0;
}
```

(But note that using `scanf` is absolutely the wrong way to read a single character.  `fgetc`, `getc`, and `getchar` are better for that.)